# Ajax, C# reading data as null when posting third level Nested node

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on a post method using Ajax in.NET Core 7. I have 3 levels of data:

[image]

Everything seems to work fine when I am sending data till level 2 "Campaigns". It read it correctly in the post method.

[image]

[image]

But as soon as I am adding Assets node. It starts showing null while retrieving.

[image]

My Ajax request is as follows:

[image]

I am using **[FormBody]** to read data but not sure what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the codes to check the model binding/model validation errors:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value?.Errors.Count > 0).Select(x => new {Key=x.Key,Errors=x.Value?.Errors}).ToList();
        }
```

For example,I tried as below:

Models:

```
public class QuickSaveFormViewModel
{
    public List<Brand>? Brands { get; set; }
}
public class Brand
{
    public  string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Currency { get; set; }

    public List<Campaign>? Campaigns { get; set; }
}

public class Campaign
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Budget { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public List<Asset>? Assets { get; set; }
}

public class Asset
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int?  BrandId { get; set; }
    public int? ChannelId { get; set; }
    public int? FormatId { get; set; }
    public int? TypeId { get; set; }

    public string? FileBase64 { get; set; }
}
```

Tried with postman:

```
{
    "brands":[{
        "Name":"Brand05",
        "Currency":"$",
        "campaigns":[{
            "Name":"Campaign1",
            "Budget":"23000",
            "StartDate":"2023-08-06",
            "EndDate":"2023-09-06",
            "ASSETS":[{
                "NAME":"ASSET 1",
                "BRANDID":"1",
                "CHANNELID":"1",
                "FormatId":"",
                "TypeId":"2",
                "FileBase64":""
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Errors:

[image]

Fixed with replace `""` with `null`:

Notice your `xxId` property in your C# codes,if they are not type of string,don't send `""`
[image]