# ASP.NET: can I check what client passed in [FromBody] myClass?

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

ASP.NET Core 6: I use `Post` method with `MyClass` parameter

```
public async Task<int> PutCustomer([FromBody] MyCustomer customer)
```

Sometimes a client Python app passed badly formatted JSON and I receive `customer ==null`.

For example, it can be when 'month' : 'May' instead of 'month' : 5 etc.

How can I get what passed client to validate the JSON, try to convert to the object or return validation error?

Comment: I think that you could create a custom model binder for this purpose. Please have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Hi,@ZedZip,in your secnario,it's a model binding error instead of model validation error,you could read the json  from HttpContext.Request.Body

Comment: And in a  webapi project,it would retrun  model validation error in response by default

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Thank you. in other words: if I received the null object then I can get and analyze request.Body? Could you show me a piece of code how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

For example,I tried as below in a middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //It's important to enable context.Request.Body to be read multipule times here
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    using StreamReader reader   = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true);     
    var  bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    var obj=System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(bodyStr);  

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

When I debug(Commented [ApiController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#apicontroller-attribute) Attribute ):

[image]

Even if you send badly formatted json,the request body won't be null,but it would failed to be deserialized to MyCustomer during model binding,then you got a null object

If you tried with a default webapi project,the response would contain the error message :

[image]

If you try with MVC projects,you may follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76847190/ajax-c-sharp-reading-data-as-null-when-posting-third-level-nested-node/76848661#76848661) to get the modelbinding/model validation errors in controller

And here's a [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878750/can-i-customize-error-messages-for-values-higher-than-allowed/76880325#76880325) related with Customizing more detailed error

If you tried with startup parttern,just  add the middleware to configure method in startup.cs:

[image]

In controller:

```
HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true);
            var bodyStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            var obj = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(bodyStr);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How to read the body in a controller method? For example, I need to check if MyCustomer is null in the Put method and just here to read what was passed? i.e. not in Startup but in the method. I can have multiple Put methods and it makes sense to retrieve body and return an error

Comment: If you tried with startup parttern,just add the middleware to configure method in startup.cs..

Comment: I have added it to Startup, its ok. How to read json from body in a controller method?

Comment: I have added to method             var body2 = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync(); but the body2 is null

Comment: I've updated the codes in controller,hopes help

Comment: Tried. HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //<-- exception the method is not supported. If I comment it then bodyStr is empty

Comment: You have to enablebuffering before the stream is read( during  modelbinding),you could enable it in a middleware /filter( before your request get into the action ) ,then you could read the request body in your controller

Comment: Also, even if you've called enablebuffering in a middleware/filter ,the position of the stream won't be adjusted by default,that's why you have to call HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);/HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0; before you read it again

Comment: Yes, I have made all as you wrote. But I during the run received an error: these methods not supported - HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);/HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;

Comment: Hi,@ZedZip,Could you share a minimal example so that I could check what caused the issue  on your side?

Comment: It is large app , it is NET6 based Program+Startup etc. May be it is the reason?

Comment: As far as I known,the error just indicates your  Body( Stream).CanSeek  property is false  when you call  HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);/HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0

Comment: And in .net core , CanSeek property of request body only has the getter , and the default value is false, and the solution to set it to true is Enablebuffering method

Comment: The codes below would replace the request body and set canseek property to true(not recommanded) ,you could check if you've replaced the body somewhere else .codes:var stream= new MemoryStream();
    await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
    context.Request.Body = stream;
    var canseek = context.Request.Body.CanSeek;